# Increase Mysql row size

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin, database, laravel

When I run a laravel migration i get an error complaining about row size how can i solve i have run a couple of commands but not changed anything

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs (SQL: alter table `patients` add `address` varchar(191) null, add `private_number` varchar(191) null, add `secret_number` varchar(191) null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated:

> You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

See the [limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html),

The total length can not exceed 65535 characters.
BLOB and TEXT columns count up to four plus eight bytes each as those are stored outside of the table.